# CSS Positioning SVG at bottom of div

Tags: html, css, image, sass, semantic-ui

I have a div that should hold a logo and an illustration. The mobile version should be 100% of the display and the image-section should fit like 60% of the screen. I am stuck at this as you can see in the image below.
I hope somebody with better CSS skills can help me with this.

[image]

Code:

```
.image-content {
      height: 500px;
      background-color: #e8f6fa;
      border: 1px solid red;
      .logo {
        visibility: hidden;
        position: absolute;
        margin: 30px auto;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        text-align: center;
        z-index: 2;
      }

      .cover-image {
        border: 1px solid blue;
        position: absolute;
      }
    }
```

JSX code:

```
 <div className='image-content'>
              <Image className='logo' src={logo} />
              <Image className='cover-image' src={coverImages[pageIndex]} />
            </div>
```

Its written with React and Semantic UI.

Rendered HTML:

```
   <div class="image-content">
    <img
      src="/static/media/intro-logo.862f85da.svg"
      class="ui image logo"
    /><img
      src="/static/media/welcome-clean-crop.a0857347.svg"
      class="ui image cover-image"
    />
  </div>
```

Border is only set for understanding purposes.

Thanks!

Comment: Try using bootstrap to detect the width of your page

Answer (score 0):

Give your cover-image img width :100% for mobile case.

**Added css that will target only for mobile cases:**

```
@media (max-width:767px){
      .cover-image{
      width:100%}
      }
```

> Bewlow is the demo:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: boder-box;
}

.image-content {
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #e8f6fa;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.logo {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 30px auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 2;
}

.cover-image {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  position: absolute;

}

@media (max-width:767px) {
  .cover-image {
    width: 100%
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="image-content">
  
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/80x80/000/f0f0f0.jpg&text=logo" class="ui image logo" />
  
  
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/350x500/red/000.jpg&text=banner" class="ui image cover-image" />
 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this on your ".image-content":

```
display: flex;
align-items: flex-end
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o48r75kd/)

Uses flexbox to align items to the end, [align-items](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items).

Comment: Please **edit your answer** and explain how this works and how this solves the problem?